# How do I fix a Syntax Error using JUnit RunWith

Tags: junit, import, junit4

I have imported the runner exactly but still I'm facing error. I'd like to know the cause/reason.

Example

```
package example.testcourse

import com.intuit.karate.junit.Karate;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; // here I got syntax error but I think it's right. So, don't know is this the error or something else 

@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class courselist{

}
```

Comment: What's the exact error? is junit library added to the class path?

Comment: Sometimes need to clean the results. Project-> Clean. I already fixed it, thank you!